# Ajax Submittions to Guest Entries

Tags: ajax, guest-entries

Does anything need to be done to allow for ajax submittions using the GuestEntries plugin? 
https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries

I'm following the method used here for Contact form, it submits fine and returns success but nothing shows up in the DB?

https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm#ajax-form-submissions

in chrome the request looks right?

```
Request URL: http://familiar.dev/
Request Method: POST
Request Payload:
{"action":"guestEntries/saveEntry","sectionId":"5","enabled":"1","redirect":"contact/thanks","title":"asdsa"}
```

any ideas?

Comment: What's the response look like in Chrome?  Anything weird getting logged in craft/storage/runtime/logs?

Comment: So i think i figured it out.  my payload was sent as json instead as regular form data.  I reformatted and everything is working!

Comment: Ahh... nice catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looks like i found the answer.  My javascript was submitting the data as json instead of as regular form data.  I reformatted and it works as expected.

Whoops.